# CSS Header Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I am new to laying out webpages without the use of tables, so my apologies if this is a really simple question.

I am attempting to create a header for a page which I want to look something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|       | Some big text                   |
|  img  |                                 |
|       | Some smaller text               |
-------------------------------------------
```

Currently I have the following div, but it does not bottom align the small text like I want:

```
<div style="height:50px;">
    <img src="img.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%; float:left"/>
    <div style="vertical-align:top;">BigText</>
    <div style="vertical-align:bottom;">SmallText</div>
</div>
```

How should I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missunderstanding the use of `vertical-align` in CSS. Read up in this tutorial, http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version: http://jsfiddle.net/gT6ze/

Alternatively, you can use `position:relative` for container `div`, set `padding:60px` for it, and position image within it with `position:absolute; top:0; left:0;`. This way `div` elements with text can also be positioned inside parent by setting `position:absolute` and `top:0` and `bottom:0`.

Comment: This is identical to mine? The small text is still not aligned with the bottom of the image.

Comment: Still not what I am looking for. I would think it would be a simple matter to align an element with the bottom of the parent div...

Comment: @FlyingStreudel OK so is this what you want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/HXT3W/ ?
This is implemented using `position` `relative` and `absolute`, I can make example using `float`s if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

use the `padding` or `margin` for the small text div

```
<div style="height:50px;">
    <img src="img.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%; float:left"/>
    <div style="vertical-align:top;">BigText</>
    <div style="vertical-align:bottom;padding-top:15px;">SmallText</div>
</div>​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/aNhZf/1/)

Comment: apply the hard-coded styles to a div? or need some other way to achieve it?

Comment: I want the small text to be aligned with the bottom of the image. I shouldnt have to measure anything by hand.